# Result in polar form, with the angle written in radians in the interval $[0, 2\pi)$, using de Moivre's theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I would like how to calculate the following in $4^{th}$ root:

$(81\cos (2\pi/3) + 81i\sin (2\pi/3))^\frac{1}{4}.$

I probably have to use de Moivre's theorem but I don't know how to start.

I have been researching but I can't find a way to find the solution. Thank you.

I tried the following:
$(81\cos (120) + 81i\sin (120)^\frac{1}{4}.$ =
$(-40.5 + 70.148i)^\frac{1}{4}.$

Comment: It's definitely de Moivre. What have you tried?

Comment: I have written what I've tried. Thank you.

Comment: What you've written isn't de Moivre's theorem. Factor out the $81$ and the very first line of the very first site you might think to look at has exactly what you need: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula In your case, $n=\frac14$.

Answer (score 1):

$(81\cos (\frac{2\pi}{3}) + 81i\sin (\frac{2\pi}{3})^\frac{1}{4}.$

Using De Moivre's to bring down the $\frac{1}{4}$

$3e^{\frac{{2\pi i}}{12}}=3e^{\frac{{\pi i}}{6}}=3\left(cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)+isin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)=3\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt3}+\frac{i}{2}\right)$

Refer-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you know about how one could define raising a complex number to a (complex) number. For instance, define for $z,w \in \mathbf{C}$ the $w$-th power of $z$ as $z^w:= \text{exp}(w \cdot \text{Log}(z))$, where $\text{Log}$ is the complex logarithm with $\text{Log}(z):= \text{log}|z| + i \cdot \text{Arg}(z)$ (principal branch; I don't know if you know these functions; Arg is the argument of the complex number and $|z|$ is the modulus of this number).

Then the calculation follows [where I use that for $x,y \in \mathbf{R}, e^{x+yi}:= e^x\cdot (\cos(y) + i\sin(y))$ ] :
\begin{align}
\left(81\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) + i \cdot 81\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{4}} &= \left(81 \cdot e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}} \right)^{\frac{1}{4}}=: e^{\frac{1}{4} \cdot \text{Log}(81e^{2\pi i/3})} =e^{\frac{1}{4} \cdot \left[ \log|81e^{2\pi i/3}| + i \cdot \text{Arg}(81e^{2\pi i/3}) \right]}\\
&= e^{\frac{1}{4} \log(81) + i\cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{2\pi}{3}} = 81^{\frac{1}{4}} \cdot e^{\frac{\pi i}{6}} = 3 \cdot e^{\frac{\pi i }{6}}.
\end{align}
I have done in it this way, so that perhaps you have a technique you can follow for different powers of different complex numbers.